# Creating shared weight connections in Pybrain

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pybrain

I am trying to create a neural network in PyBrain which utilizes shared weight connections, but am having trouble doing so. I haven't found too many examples which use these type of connections, but had thought that I had gleaned the way to use them from those that I found and the source code. But apparently I was not so lucky.

As a simple example, I'm trying to create the following shared weight neural network:
[image: a simple SWNN]

The connections shown in rectangles I would like to be shared, in that the weights along each path are the same (swapping the input vector [x,y] with [y,x] should yield the same output).

I attempted to build this architecture with the following code:

```
from pybrain.structure.modules.linearlayer import LinearLayer
from pybrain.structure.modules.sigmoidlayer import SigmoidLayer
from pybrain.structure.moduleslice import ModuleSlice
from pybrain.structure.networks.feedforward import FeedForwardNetwork
from pybrain.structure.connections.shared import MotherConnection,SharedFullConnection

net=FeedForwardNetwork()

# make modules
inp=LinearLayer(2,name='input')
h1=SigmoidLayer(2,name='hidden')
outp=LinearLayer(1,name='output')

# now add modules
net.addOutputModule(outp)
net.addInputModule(inp)
net.addModule(h1)

# now we need to create the connections
mc=MotherConnection(2,name='mother') 
mc2=MotherConnection(2,name='mother2')
topInput=ModuleSlice(inp,outSliceFrom=0,outSliceTo=1)
bottomInput=ModuleSlice(inp,outSliceFrom=1,outSliceTo=2)
topHidden=ModuleSlice(h1,inSliceFrom=0,inSliceTo=1)
bottomHidden=ModuleSlice(h1,inSliceFrom=1,inSliceTo=2)
net.addConnection(SharedFullConnection(mc,topInput,topHidden))
net.addConnection(SharedFullConnection(mc,bottomInput,bottomHidden))
net.addConnection(SharedFullConnection(mc2,topHidden,outp))
net.addConnection(SharedFullConnection(mc2,bottomHidden,outp))

# finish up
net.sortModules()

#print net.activate([2,1])
```

In the above code I created two MotherConnections, mc and mc2, the idea being that these two objects would hold the shared weights in my first and second rectangle, respectively, shown in the figure. I then used ModuleSlice to divvy up the input module and the hidden module into two groups. I then tried to addConnections using the mc and mc2 containers to connect these paths.

I do not get an error by running the above code. But if I try to test the network by uncommenting the net.activate statement at the end, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 38, in <module>
    print net.activate([2,1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/structure/networks/feedforward.py", line 19, in activate
    return super(FeedForwardNetworkComponent, self).activate(inpt)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-   py2.7.egg/pybrain/structure/modules/module.py", line 123, in activate
    self.forward()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/structure/modules/module.py", line 75, in forward
    self.outputbuffer[self.offset])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-  py2.7.egg/pybrain/structure/networks/feedforward.py", line 32, in _forwardImplementation
    c.forward()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/structure/connections/connection.py", line 77, in forward
    self.outmod.inputbuffer[outmodOffset, self.outSliceFrom:self.outSliceTo])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/structure/connections/shared.py", line 64, in _forwardImplementation
    FullConnection._forwardImplementation(self, inbuf, outbuf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/structure/connections/full.py", line 19, in _forwardImplementation
    outbuf += dot(reshape(self.params, (self.outdim, self.indim)), inbuf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 171, in reshape
    return reshape(newshape, order=order)
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

so I imagine I must be misunderstanding something about the way this is set up. Many thanks to anyone who can point out where in my understanding of these commands I'm going astray!

Answer (score 2):

I may have figured out the problem.  I think I should have included outSlices in my hidden layer definitions for topHidden and bottomHidden,such as

```
topHidden=ModuleSlice(h1,inSliceFrom=0,inSliceTo=1,outSliceFrom=0,outSliceTo=1)
bottomHidden=ModuleSlice(h1,inSliceFrom=1,inSliceTo=2,outSliceFrom=1,outSliceTo=2)
```

Naively I guess I thought this wasn't necessary since the outputs of everything in the hidden layer was being connected to the output layer. However, if this is not done then it seems the hidden layer doesn't have the correct outdim(ension) and results in the above error.
Additionally, the MotherConnections should have been defined like so:

```
mc=MotherConnection(1,name='mother')
mc2=MotherConnection(1,name='mother2')
```

I haven't tested this network extensively yet, but it no longer seems to have the above problem.